# How do i change the current item on the navigationbar in xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have been spending too much time on this one thing and I need answers. I'm using Android.Support.Design.Widget.BottomNavigationView and I do not know how to set the item to one of my choices.

I found [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView#setSelectedItemId(int)), but I guess C# doesn't have the same methods as Java or something. Don't you dare say this is a duplicate because I have searched high and low for answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change current item, you can consider to do something in BottomNavigation_NavigationItemSelected event, here is the article you can take a look:

[Bottom Navigation view](https://blog.xamarin.com/exploring-androids-bottom-navigation-view/)

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin.Android, selecting item in BottomNavigationView can be done as follows:

```
bottom_navigation_view.SelectedItemId = itemId;
```

where,
bottom_navigation_view is your BottomNavigationView and itemId is Resource Id of the menu Item to be selected.